# DRM framework for Mac applications

Tags: macos, drm

I've tried googling to no avail - are there any good libraries or frameworks for adding DRM to Mac applications?  I'm looking to sell an application outside the app store.  Is there an open source option for this, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

If by "DRM" you are talking about licensing/serialization of your app, check out Aquatic Prime:

http://www.tempel.org/UsingAquaticPrime
https://github.com/bdrister/AquaticPrime

Answer (score 0):

[Watchdog](https://github.com/konstantinpavlikhin/Watchdog) — simple registration framework for OS X apps.